# need help with excel vlookup

Tags: excel, vlookup

```
=IF(N101<>"",ROUND(VLOOKUP($N101,$I$30:$U$39,12,FALSE)/(1-(U$96+U$98)),0),0)
```

That is the current VLOOKUP in the spreadsheet that is returning the wrong data. I didnt write it, it was on a spreadsheet before i came to the company.

What I want to happen is look up the value in $N101 then i want it to find the row that is the same from i30 to i40 take whats in ((k30-j30/)/(1-(U$96+U$98))
when i say k30 i actually mean k30-k40 depending on the match.

This would really help me out

[image]

[image]

Comment: @bugz: Can you post some sample data?  What does the function return that is "the wrong data"? Do you have 11 unique values in the range I30:I40? (Also, you implicitly state that you're looking for the lookup value in I30:I40, but your formula says that you're looking in I30:I39).

Comment: i added images thanks for your help this should have been simple

Comment: @bugz: I've looked at the above images and believe that I understand the functions and references.  One question: the cell that you have selected in the first image, AC101, references a cell one row below it, N102.  Is it possible that your relative references are off by one row, or did you intend the references to work that way?

Comment: no that is a mistake as i have gone crazy trying to fix this that i probably copied and pasted the one for the row below

Comment: @bugz: Also, what's the value of cell T30?

Comment: =Q30*VLOOKUP($O30,$U$6:$V$10,2,0)
or
 $3,486.38

Comment: @I'm trying to compute what the result for AC101 should be. Assuming that the value in AC101 is -1,974 (which is what it is in the first image), the value in T30 would have to be approximately -1,549.59, which is 3,486.38 / -2.25. Did a division factor of approximately -2 enter your calculations somewhere in the worksheet?

Comment: AC101 should equal = $1,974

=IF(N102<>"",ROUND((K$30-J$30)/(1-(U$96+U$98)),0),0)

Comment: the formula is the (sgl rate - dbl rate)/ (1-(U$96+U$98))  where u96 is 17 and u98 2.5

Comment: @bugz: In the first image, U96 is 19.0%, not 17.0%.

Comment: ahh yah its 19.0 + 2.5 and 
AC101 is not supposed to be -1974 it should be positive 1974 the reason it is negative is when i took the picture i was doing j$30-k$30 not the other way around

Comment: @bugz: Please clarify - you are not interested in =IF(N101<>"",ROUND(VLOOKUP($N101,$I$30:$U$39,12,FALSE)/(1-(U$96+U$98)),0),0) in cell AC101, but rather =IF(N101<>"",ROUND((K$30-J$30)/(1-(U$96+U$98)),0),0) in cell AC101?

Comment: hmm i want =IF(N101<>"",ROUND(VLOOKUP($N101,$I$30:$U$39,12,FALSE)/(1-(U$96+U$98)),0),0) but based on the vlookup ((K$30-J$30) could become ((K$31-J$31) depending on the cabin vlookup or ((K$32-J$32) and so on . sry for the misunderstanding

Comment: @bugz: the function VLOOKUP($N101,$I$30:$U$39,12,FALSE) returns a value from column T (this is why I was interested in the value of T30) since column T is 12 columns from column I (I = 1, J = 2, ..., T = 12).  Is this the value that you expected to be looked up?

Comment: @bugz: Did that solve your mystery?  If so, I'll post it as answer if you'd like to accept it as 'the' answer.

Comment: Yes it did as i didnt realize 12 was the column int and i had to make a new column with k32-j32 and just used that in the vlookup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`=IF(N101<>"",ROUND(VLOOKUP($N101,$I$30:$U$39,#COL,FALSE)/(1-(U$96+U$98)),0),0)`

where #COL is the integer that corresponds to the column containing the resulting value from K$30-J$30 (for example).

Answer (score 0):

> VLOOKUP($N101,$I$30:$U$39,12,FALSE)

you say i30 to i 40 but you have mentioned I30 to U39. you might want to change that.

> k30 i actually mean k30-k40 depending
>   on the match.

if you mean when you put same formula on below cell then, when you drag this you'll get them automatically. Please check j30, you might want to make j$30$ if you want to always use J30.

I would also suggest checking each of the formula separately and then combine it.

Comment: =IF(N102<>"",ROUND((K$30-J$30)/(1-(U$96+U$98)),0),0) 
this is what i wante but with the vlookup